# Is it possible to create a photo filter program like Instagram using java?

Tags: java, image-processing, filter, photo

Is it possible to create a photo filter program like Instagram using java?  It doesnt have to be a mobile application with all the bells and whistles of geotagging, uploads, commenting and other social media functions. Im just interested in the photo filtering capabilities of Java.
If so a code snippet or a link to the tutorial would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Here is a site with a lot of filter examples: http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html

Comment: to answer the question asked, yes it is possible. Java is Turing complete, so it's possible to create any program you've seen created in any other Turing complete language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, Java has built-in libraries necessary to do arbitrary image analysis and processing such as that required for effects like Instagram, etc.

There are tons of resources on the web discussing the possibilities and technical approaches; try searching keywords such as "java image processing".  This website ([*Jerry's Java Image Processing Pages*](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/)) has lots of ideas.

Comment: i am trying to implement the same as the op's question but i need only for 2 effects 

polarization
nuetral density

i am not able to find anly library android or java based . do you have any idea about these?